# Append the line contents to the same line in Sublime Text 2 (for multiple lines)

Tags: sublimetext2

I use Sublime Text 2.
I have several lines, for example:

```
line one,
line two,
line three,
```

I have many more than that 8)

I want to append the contents of each line to the end of respective line. So, the result looks like this:

```
line one,line one,
line two,line two,
line three,line three,
```

Is there a fast way to do it in Sublime Text 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple:

1. Select the desired lines
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to create multiple selection from lines (`"split_selection_into_lines"` command in key bindings)
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate the selection (`"duplicate_line"` command)